# Reachability.h boolean variable connectionRequired--what does this mean in plain terms?

Tags: ios, networking, reachability

What does the connectionRequired variable mean in the Reachability.h class that Apple wrote? In plain English?

```
//WWAN may be available, but not active until a connection has been established.
//WiFi may require a connection for VPN on Demand.
- (BOOL) connectionRequired;
```

Does it mean:

--you could connect, but you haven't connected?
--you need a password
--you need VPN

When do I need to check to see if this variable is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that the cellphone has an available internet connection but is configured to tunnel the connection through a VPN and cannot connect to the VPN server. Phones configured this way are often company phones and it is done to allow access to intranet's and tracking phone activity etc.

Ideally you should always check this when you check for internet connectivity as the phone will not be able to fetch any data until the VPN server is available again unless the owner switches it off in Settings.

Comment: OK, thanks this was helpful b/c I had forgotten about the VPN option in the default Settings app.

Answer (score 0):

From Reachability.m

```
    if ((flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionRequired) == 0)
    {
        // if target host is reachable and no connection is required
        //  then we'll assume (for now) that your on Wi-Fi
        retVal = ReachableViaWiFi;
    }
```

...

```
- (BOOL) connectionRequired;
{
    NSAssert(reachabilityRef != NULL, @"connectionRequired called with NULL reachabilityRef");
    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
    if (SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachabilityRef, &flags))
    {
        return (flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionRequired);
    }
    return NO;
}
```

From AppDelegate.m

```
    if(connectionRequired)
    {
        baseLabel=  @"Cellular data network is available.\n  Internet traffic will be routed through it after a connection is established.";
    }
    else
    {
        baseLabel=  @"Cellular data network is active.\n  Internet traffic will be routed through it.";
    }
```

So it roughly says whether device uses Wi-Fi or 3G and whether connection is active or device will establish it. And if user uses VPN, device will ask him to establish VPN connection first.